# Statically Generate Shopify Theme Template from Data File

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid, static-site

How do I tell Shopify to iterate over a custom collection in a Liquid template from a static data file ala Jekyll e.g. to list the names of our stores without mutating the Shopify database (e.g. PUT/POST /admin/pages.json)?

E.g. in Jekyll you can have a folder called `_things` with N files like `thing1.json`, `thing2.json`, etc. and loop over these in a template via `for thing in site.data.things ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just paste the JSON representing your special data into a file asset, and you can then access and use that file anywhere you want in your Shopify Theme to show off whatever it is that data represents... simple.

Be aware that Shopify is not Jekyll-ish. Never has been. Never will be. Although they do share the fact that they use Liquid to render templates into HTML.

Comment: Have you tried to do this server-side in a Liquid template? I can only do it client-side.

Comment: If you want to do server-side data manipulations with metafields, then you get the chore of building your own data parser using the primitives of Liquid. Have fun. Enjoy yourself!